# How to enable full error messages in apache + passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, apache, passenger

Im building my first Rails app server on a Ubuntu server machine. I came to the point where i am testing a simple add located on the server. When I hit the root page, default rails message

"Welcome on board, You’re riding Ruby on Rails!"

Thats good i suspect. But when I hit server/todos i just get this error message

"We're sorry, but something went wrong."

How can I see full error message? I am completely new to Apache and Passenger. I suspect I could  get full messages if i run from the server but there is no GUI or browser installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok found out this was all connected to the Rails app and not a Apache or Passenger setting.

```
 # environments/production.rb
 config.consider_all_requests_local = true
```